# Unable to pass parameters of the custom object using param tag in custom controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have 2 custom objects Position and candidate,i have created a pageblock table in VF page for Positions records to display,whenever i click the positions  record, all the candidates record related to that position has to be displayed.But am not able to display the related candidates records when i click any position record on VF page.

```
 <apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" controller="positioncandidateparamcon">
    <apex:form >
     <apex:pageBlock > 
       <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!pos}" var="p">
         <apex:column headerValue="POSITION">
           <apex:commandLink action="{!getcandidate}" reRender="candidateinfo">
            <apex:outputText value="{!p.name}"/> 
            <apex:param name="idcandidate" value="{!p.id}" assignTo="{!selectedcandidate}"/>
            </apex:commandLink> 
         </apex:column>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>

                     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!can}" var="c" id="candidateinfo">
                       <apex:column value="{!c.name}"/>
                     </apex:pageBlockTable>
     </apex:pageBlock>


    </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class positioncandidateparamcon {



      public list<Candidate__c>can{set;get;}
      public string selectedcandidate{get;set;}
      public Position__c pos {set;}



      public list<Position__c >getpos(){
         list<Position__c >pos1=[SELECT id,name from Position__c limit:5];
         return pos1;
        }


       public void getcandidate() {
           can = [select id,name from Candidate__c where Id=:selectedcandidate ];
    }


}
```

something is missing in the below line,am not able to match position id with candidate.

> can = [select id,name from Candidate__c where Id=:selectedcandidate ];

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
<apex:param name="idcandidate" value="{!p.id}" assignTo="{!selectedcandidate}"/>
```

This is setting `selectedcandidate` not to the ID of the Candidate, but to the ID of the Position.  Therefore when you search for the candidate:

```
can = [select id,name from Candidate__c where Id=:selectedcandidate ];
```

You won't get any results, because you're searching for the ID of the position.

You need to change the `value` attribute of your `<apex:param>` to the field that contains the Candidate ID, e.g. `p.Candidate__c`, instead of its own ID.

Comment: @Rob...thanks for your rerply... i tried to make the changes as u suggested but am not getting the result,can you please edit and repost the code,as am new to salesforce plz do helpme .

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific - what issue do you have now?

Comment: Ok....let me take this example  i have created a pageblock table which shows all the Account Records, when i click on any of the Account , i can c all the related contacts with in that page.

Comment: controller  : public void Accountclicked() {
        contactinformation=[SELECT id,firstname,lastname from CONTACT WHERE AccountID=:selectedaccount];   
    }                                                                                                      <apex:outputText value="{!acc.name}"/>
        <apex:param name="id" value="{!acc.id}" assignTo="{!selectedaccount}"/> 
        </apex:commandLink>

Comment: in the above query *WHERE AccountID=:selectedaccount * am using this to get related contacts,but am not able to write cross object query for those 2 objects postion and candidante.

Comment: ...i hope this info will help you to understand what my issue is,thanks in advance.